# Assert won't display the error message

Tags: c++, message, assert

I'm having a weird problem with assert in Visual C++ 2005. I've tried to introduce asserts into my program and no matter what asserts I try to use (assert() or BOOST_ASSERT_MSG) it gives the exact same error message which tells me nothing other than that a debug error occurred.

> Debug Error!
>
> Program: ...
>
> This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
>      Please contact the support team for more information.
>
> (Press Retry to Debug the application)

Here's the boost assertion that I'm using

```
BOOST_ASSERT_MSG(deathRow.size() >= 3, "There are less than 3 blocks being deleted!");
```

And yes, it gives the exact same error message as:

```
assert(deathRow.size() >= 3 && "There are less than 3 blocks being deleted");
```

Nondescript error happens, no matter what project I'm using, new or old.

I have no idea why. I know I used asserts before in another program and didn't have this problem. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use Microsoft's [`_ASSERTE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezb1wyez.aspx) macro (note the <kbd>E</kbd> for *Expression*) then the message will also appear in assert dialog.

The reason both versions of `ASSERT` exist is that both have advantages and disadvantages and you get to choose which you want.

- `_ASSERTE` gives better diagnostics but results in slightly bigger binaries (since the textual representation of the expression must be included in the binary)
- `_ASSERT` give less information in the assert dialog but results in smaller binaries.

Since both flavours only produce code in debug build I tend to always use `_ASSERTE` because the size of the binary is hardly effected and doesn't matter much in debug builds.

Comment: Ah yes, that seems to work. Thanks, guess I'll use _ASSERTE then. Would still kind of like to know why the other asserts aren't working though.

Comment: @Mathmagician the other versions are working they're just less descriptive, I've updated my answer to reflect why you might want that.